# setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adDescription.'

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I can not create a method to create an advert and envialo to the database. the error is "setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adDescription.'" this and happens only when redirect me to announce registration of view

this is the record of view:

```
#import "AddAdViewController.h"
#import "Ads.h"
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "AdsTableViewController.h"


@interface AddAdViewController () <JVWebServiceDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL show;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *currentTextField;
@end

@implementation AddAdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (IBAction)addAd:(id)sender {


    if (self.adTitleField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa nos informar seu nome completo." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.adPriceField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa nos informar um e-mail para contato." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.adLocalField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa criar uma senha para a sua conta." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.adDescriptionField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa confirmar sua senha." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    }  else {
            Ads *newAd = [Ads new];
            newAd.title = self.adTitleField.text;
            newAd.price = self.adPriceField.text;
            newAd.local = self.adLocalField.text;
            newAd.description = self.adDescriptionField.text;


            [[JVWebService sharedService] setServiceDelegate:self];
            [[JVWebService sharedService] postAd:newAd];

        }

}


#pragma mark - Bar Button Action

- (void)cancelButtonAction {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - JVWebService Delegate

- (void)successfulRequestDidReturnObject:(NSObject *)object {

    [JVUtils showMessage:@"Agora você tem uma conta JáVendi! Faça o login e desfrute ao máximo do aplicativo." withTitle:@"Parabéns!"];

    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    AdsTableViewController *svc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:svc]
                                            animated:YES
                                          completion:nil];




}

- (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [JVUtils showMessage:error.localizedDescription withTitle:@"Erro"];
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you are trying to set a property called 'adDescription' on an object that does not have an adDescription property. I don't see you directly referencing this variable, so it is probably getting set in one of your setters, particularly where you make the Ads, or this line

```
[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];
```